# CVE-2021-4034 : __environ is init before the GCONV_PATH injection

Tags: exploit, vulnerability

I am a bit late to the party but I decided to look into the polkit vulnerability (CVE-2021-4034).

I get that the code injection comes from iconv loading an arbitrary library file through the `GCONV_PATH` environment variable.
However I can't get my head around why it works since this variable is checked in `__gconv_load_cache()` with `getenv()`. `getenv()` does not rely on the original `envp` pointer but on `__environ` which is a full copy of `envp` created during the glibc starting phase.

At the time of `__environ` initialization `GCONV_PATH` is not present in `envp`, therefore `getenv()` cannot find it.

What am I missing ?

---

Backtrace :
log_message
g_printerr
g_convert
g_iconv_open
iconv_open
__gconv_load_cache
getenv

```
int
__gconv_load_cache (void)
{
  int fd;
  struct __stat64_t64 st;
  struct gconvcache_header *header;

  /* We cannot use the cache if the GCONV_PATH environment variable is
     set.  */
  __gconv_path_envvar = getenv ("GCONV_PATH");
  if (__gconv_path_envvar != NULL)
    return -1;

    ...
```

```
char *
getenv (const char *name)
{
  char **ep;
  uint16_t name_start;

  if (__environ == NULL || name[0] == '\0')
    return NULL;

    ...

      for (ep = __environ; *ep != NULL; ++ep)
    ...
}
```

---

edit : modify `argv` to `envp`.

Comment: AFAIK the issue is the following: 1) Env variables are placed in memory right after `argv` 2) End of `argv` is signalled by a `NULL` 3) The code processing the `argv` options in `pkexec` started checking from index `1` instead of `0` 4) The code processing `argv` at some point wrote back a value in the `argv` array 5)By putting `NULL` at index `0` you could basically trick `pkexec` to read *out of bounds* of `argv` (i.e. into env variables which follow immediately), so you could basically write an env variable.

Comment: The kernel when you spawn a child process will check/clear a number of env variables to avoid security issues.. But this bug allowed you to control an env var *after* it was checked/cleared by the kernel when spawning pkexec, thus breaking these security controls. [This youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eTcVLqKpZJc) has a very clear explanation.

Comment: Oups, I made a mistake and mixed up ```argv``` and ```envp```. I edited the post.